# What are molecular species?

Tags: physical-chemistry, molecules, surface-chemistry, adsorption

I am in high school learning about adsorption for the first time. My school textbook   says:

> "The accumulation of **molecular species** at the surface rather than in the bulk of a solid or liquid is termed adsoption" (Definition 1).

And I started thinking what does **molecular species** mean. So I checked out [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adsorption):

> Adsorption is the adhesion of atoms, ions or molecules from a gas, liquid or dissolved solid to a surface (Defiinition 2).

So does the word **molecular species** in definition 1 refer to **atoms,ions and molecules.**(Definition 2)?

Also definition 1 mentions that this phenomenon takes place on the surface of a solid or liquid; why does it not mention gases?

Comment: Can you imagine molecules of gas get adsorbed on the surface of other gas ?

Comment: A species (or chemical species) is an atom, ion, or molecule, basically anything that can appear in a chemical equation as reactant or product. It seems weird to include atoms in molecular species, but from the context of the definition, I would think they wanted to include atoms in their definition.

Comment: @Poutnik no i can't imagine that but adsorption can happen at the interface of a gas and solid i guess so can i say that the solid is getting adsorbed.

Comment: @KarstenTheis so molecular species would usually mean molecules??

Comment: No, the solid does not get adsorbed, it stays where it is.

Comment: I don't know what molecular species would mean, probably molecules and molecular ions.

Answer (score 0):

> So does the word molecular species in definition 1 refer to atoms,ions and molecules.(Definition 2)?

It is most probably referring to molecules.

> Also definition 1 mentions that this phenomenon takes place on the surface of a solid or liquid why does it not mention gases?

That's because gases as such, do not have what you would call a "well-defined surface" unlike solids and liquids.

Answer (score -1):

I start with an example of the use of the term 'molecular species' in practice, to quote from ['Periodic Trends among Interstellar Molecular Species: The Case of Oxygen- and Sulfur-Containing Species'](https://www.intechopen.com/books/basic-concepts-viewed-from-frontier-in-inorganic-coordination-chemistry/periodic-trends-among-interstellar-molecular-species-the-case-of-oxygen-and-sulfur-containing-specie):

> In the present work, the effect interstellar hydrogen bonding on the variation of the S/O abundance ratio with respect to the cosmic S/O ratio is examined using high-level quantum chemical simulations. The binding energy between water molecule on the surface of the dust grains and the O- or S-containing molecule gives inside about the level to which the interstellar abundance of such molecule is affected. There are 59 O-containing and 19 S-containing interstellar species; for 16 that are S and O analogues, there is no order regarding their astronomical observations, i.e., in some cases, the O-containing species was observed before the S-containing and vice versa. Thus, the observation of one always gives information about the presence and the possible detectability of the order. In the light of this, the known molecules from this S/O group whose corresponding analogues are not yet observed are examined for their possible detectability. These species are subjected to the effect of interstellar hydrogen bonding.

The above context appears to be consistence with this [Wikipedia description](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chemical_species) for chemical species:

> Generally, a chemical species can be defined as an ensemble of chemically identical molecular entities that can explore the same set of molecular energy levels on a defined time scale.

So, it appears that terms 'molecular species' and 'chemical species' are pretty much synonymous.